# Implementing SpeechSynthesisUtterance() TTS via javascript and android Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, text-to-speech

I am trying to call *SpeechSynthesisUtterance()* via javascript in order to make it work under **Android Chrome** (as I've read this specific function is compatible with Android Chrome). So, I wrote a short demo but I do not know how to link it with Android Chrome. I call the window function but it does not work. Please inform me if it is not an appropriate question for here, in order to delete it.

```
<button id="ButtonPlay">TTS demo</button>

<script>
    function WhatToPlay(text) {    
        var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();    
        msg.text = text;
        window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
    }

    $("#ButtonPlay").click(function() {
        WhatToPlay("Hello world");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this basic code on Android Chrome and it works so if it doesn't on yours doesn't there must be something else wrong e.g. the device itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<button type="button" id="speakBtn">Speak</button>

<script>
  const speak = () => {
    const utter = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    utter.text = "Hello";
    speechSynthesis.cancel();
    speechSynthesis.speak(utter);
  }
  speakBtn.addEventListener('click', speak);
  speechSynthesis.getVoices();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it a lot for your effort and recommendation.